# Which FFT algorithm does `Fourier[...]` use?

Tags: fourier-analysis, implementation-details

Does anyone know which Fast Fourier Transform algorithm Mathematica uses to compute a Discrete Fourier Transform using `Fourier[...]`, and is there any option to change the algorithm to that of another type?

E.g. Cooley-Tukey (most common), or Bruun's Algorithm?

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to change the algorithm or the scaling? The latter is done using the option `FourierParameters`.

Comment: @Hugh I was hoping it would be you to answer! The actual option used to computer the DFT to make it an actual FFT --  if it exists. I assumed MM uses the Cooley-Tukey because this seems to be the most commonly applied but I can't find this in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know the algorithm used, sorry. A good question to ask.  [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FastFourierTransform.html) discusses possible algorithms but does not state which is used in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, the MathWorld link is a nice resource.

Comment: I believe that the FFT provided by the Intel MKL is used. If that helps anything.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Actually it does. Do you have a source for that by any chance?

Comment: Relevant (but as vague as we are used it by WRI ;)) https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html The MKL is mentioned there _with no word_ although I actually know that it is used at least _somewhere_...

Comment: WRI support has sometimes been open to questions like this.

Comment: If there was an option to specify algorithm, it would be documented, I would think. Why does it matter which algorithm is used?

Comment: @Somos FFT algorithms can induce errors the type and size of error is dependent on the FFT algorithm. If you are trying to simulate the behavior of your FFT -- it matters!

Comment: `"FourierOptions" /. SystemOptions[]` will give some information though it will not indicate alternatives.

Comment: You can also use `SystemOptions["FourierOptions"]` directly, as an alternative to @Daniel's suggestion. On a different note, I had (apparently mistakenly) thought *Mathematica* was now using FFTW.

Comment: Fantastic thank you all for the contributions. I'll post an answer based on your suggestions later.

Comment: You could pick up a book on Numerical Analysis (e.g., Burden and Faires) and/or Numerical Recipes (Press, et al.) and write your own implementation of the Fast Fourier Transform.   Then compare it to Wolfram's for accuracy or speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's contributions on this. After some further research it appears that the FFT Mathematica uses is indeed from Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL) and they give some details in their documentation [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-fourier-transform-functions).

The reason I wanted to know this is that apparently different implementations of the FFT can introduce errors and artifacts that vary from algorithm to algorithm.